# second mysqli_query fails

Tags: php, html

the first query is fine but the second one wont work it just dies.
I plug the `$city` variable into the second one and echo it back and it shows the correct 
value but its the the actual:

```
$row = mysqli_query($dbc, $query)
  or die('Error while querying the Database');
```

that fails... please help!

```
        $dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME)
            or WriteMessage('Error', 'Could not connect to the Database...');

    //get user city...

    $userID = $_SESSION['userID'];
    $queryUserCity = "SELECT * from user where userID = $userID";
    $GetResult = mysqli_query($dbc, $queryUserCity)
     or die('Error while querying the Database');

    $getRow = mysqli_fetch_array($GetResult);
    $city = $getRow['city'];
    $state = $getRow['state'];
    $username = $getRow['username'];

    echo 'username='.$username.' ';
    echo 'city='.$city;
    echo 'state = ' .$state;



        $query = "SELECT * FROM adds where city = $city  ORDER BY addDate ASC";          
        //fails right here...

 /*-->*/       $row = mysqli_query($dbc, $query)
               or die('Error while querying the Database');

        echo $query;
        exit();
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data))
        {
```

Comment: `city = $city` should be `city = '$city'` String encapsulation is a must when the variable is anything other than an integer.

Comment: You might want to try your SQL statement in your database first. Some databases also help you creating those queries. Then you use the statement which worked, and you are fine.

Comment: to be safe with multiple query always use transaction

Comment: Why are you using two queries instead of a `JOIN` between the `user` and `adds` table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to find a string without single quote. You use `integer` without `single quote` but in case of string you have to use `single quote` with your `string`.

change

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM adds where city = $city  ORDER BY addDate ASC";
```

to

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM adds where city = '$city'  ORDER BY addDate ASC";
```

and to find out exact error try to use the below code.

```
if (!mysqli_query($dbc, $query)){
     echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($dbc));
}
```

Comment: thanks Ram, but i have actually echoed it back just the way it is.. and it the query works fine... also if we take a look at the first query the variable $userID is also without sinle quote ''...

Comment: You can compare/find integer without single quote but in case of string you have to use single quote.

Comment: I just edit my answer to find out the exact error can you try that to know the exact error?

Comment: i found out the problem you are awesome!

Comment: i really appreciate you help

Comment: I glad to help you out :)

Comment: by the way the error was this  description: Unknown column 'city' in 'where clause'

Answer (score 1):

If the city is a textual type (and it probably is), you'll need:

```
... where city = '$city' ...
```

But, in fact, you shouldn't really be doing it that way anyway, since it opens you up to the possibility of SQL injection attacks if someone can enter arbitrary text for their city.

You should start looking into parameterised queries since they can protect you from such attacks. See [Exploits of a Mom](http://xkcd.com/327/) and the invaluable [explain-xkcd](http://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/327:_Exploits_of_a_Mom) entry.